# Configuring Firefox to access Tor network and SSH tunnel server

Tags: configuration, firefox, ssh

I would like to access the Tor network (hidden services/.onion sites) and Http sites using Firefox. I currently route Firefox and a download manager to access Http sites through an SSH tunnel server. I can also access the Tor network with the ***Tor Browser*** and access .onion sites. But I haven't figured out how to route Firefox to access both the Tor network (.onion) and Http sites seamlessly. I  have tried to configure ProxyCap (Freecap for Mac) to do this but am not sure how to configure it to enable Firefox to do this. Everything I've tried has only been partially successful. I've read that generally you want to route traffic according to this protocol ...Firefox -> Tor -> Proxycap -> SSH server to prevent DNS leaks, etc. Is this correct? If so what are general configuration settings?

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are asking for. Do you mean that you do not care at all about anonymity, and just want to make your Firefox able to access .onion sites too? Or do you expect that all web traffic should be routed through Tor, anonymously? Or do you want to route all non-onion traffic through Tor and then a proxy (at the exit side), but .onion sites just through Tor (no additional proxy)? Something else?